# How to use guizero slider to change global variable? (Python)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, guizero

I'm quite new to programming and I am trying to control a DC motor with a raspberry pi. I'm trying to use a guizero slider to change a global variable `motorspeed` however if I run the code the motor will only run on the initial variable set.

Thank you ever so much!

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
from guizero import App, Text, TextBox, PushButton, Slider

#GPIO SETUP
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.LOW)

motorspeed = 50

def changemotorspeed(slider_value):
    global motorspeed
    slider_value = motorspeed

#MOTOR SETUP
def motorstart():
    GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.HIGH)
    pwm = GPIO.PWM(13, 100)
    pwm.start(0)
    pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(motorspeed)
    sleep(1)
        
def motorstop():
    GPIO.cleanup()
    
#GUI SETUP
app = App(title = "MOTOR CONTROL")
start_button = PushButton(app, text = "START", command = motorstart)
stop_button = PushButton(app, text = "STOP", command = motorstop)
text_size = Slider(app, command = changemotorspeed, start = 0, end = 100)
app.display()
```

Comment: This is just a guess but try changing  slider_value = motorspeed to motorspeed=int(slider_value)  please tell me if this helps.

Comment: @PurpleLlama Yep that worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you set ***slider_value=motorspeed***  it locks the slider value instead of changing the motorspeed.

**Change to this**

```
motorspeed = slider_value
```